# How to make photo grid without any bounds?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gridview

I want to make photogrid like [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/aweditorium/id399946763?mt=8).

I know that I can do this using `UIClollectionView` or any other `demos` available in cocoa controls , but the issue of using all these is that `i can not move the grid view in any direction` i.e i can move only in horizontal or vertical directions but not in z axis direction (i.e scrolling horizontal and vertical directions at the same time).

```
I want the grid view to move in any directions.
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks..

Comment: "z axis" does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @Kreiri - Ya i know, but  i just wanted to explain that i want to move grid in any direction.

Comment: It sounds like to want to disable the directional lock.
Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001938/uiscrollview-scrolling-in-only-one-direction-at-a-time)