# Disable diagonal dragging in UIScrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I am using UIScrollview to load my two views let say **A** and **B**. It exactly looks like the below picture. I set **PagingEnabled** as **YES** and **DirectionLockEnabled** as **YES**.

When I drag the view from A to B it goes diagonally. Please find the code below,

```
- (void)setupScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrMain {

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            // View A
            [ViewA setFrame:CGRectMake((i)*scrollview.frame.size.width + 20, 0, scrollview.frame.size.width - 40, ViewA.frame.size.height)];
            [scrollview addSubview:ViewA];
        } else if (i == 1) {
           // View B
           [ViewB setFrame:CGRectMake((i)*ViewB.frame.size.width + 30, 0, scrollview.frame.size.width - 40, ViewB.frame.size.height)];
           [scrollview addSubview:ViewB];
        }
    }
    [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake((scrollview.frame.size.width-15)*2, ViewB.frame.size.height)];
}

- (void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging: (UIScrollView *) scrollView
{
    self.oldContentOffset = scroller.contentOffset;
}

- (void) scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) scrollView
{
    float XOffset = fabs(self.oldContentOffset.x - scrollView.contentOffset.x );
    float YOffset = fabs(self.oldContentOffset.y - scrollView.contentOffset.y );

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x != self.oldContentOffset.x && (XOffset >= YOffset) )
    {
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
        scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    }
    else
    {
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
        scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionVertical;
    }

}
```

[image]

I check with these following links but I did't get a solution yet,
http://bogdanconstantinescu.com/blog/proper-direction-lock-for-uiscrollview.html
[UIScrollView scrolling in only one direction at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001938/uiscrollview-scrolling-in-only-one-direction-at-a-time)
http://chandanshetty01.blogspot.ae/2012/07/restricting-diagonal-scrolling-in.html

All Helps are appreciated!!

Comment: The way I did it was just not allowing the scrollview containing the pages scroll 2 ways (So just horizontally in this case). And allow the views (A and B in this case) in that scrollview have their own way of scrolling (vertically in this case).

Answer (score 1):

set `directionalLockEnabled = YES;` after you reset the contentSize of the scrollview

```
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((self.scrollView.frame.size.width-15)*2, self.ViewB.frame.size.height)];
self.scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES; // add this here.
```

By doing like this, it will fix your issue

**Answer based on your code**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupScrollView:self.scrollView];
    self.scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)setupScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrMain {

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        // View A
        self.ViewA = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.ViewA.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self.ViewA setFrame:CGRectMake((i)*self.scrollView.frame.size.width + 20, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width - 40, 800)];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.ViewA];
    } else if (i == 1) {
        // View B
        self.ViewB = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.ViewB.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [self.ViewB setFrame:CGRectMake((i)*self.ViewA.frame.size.width + 30, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width - 40, 800)];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.ViewB];
    }
}
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((self.scrollView.frame.size.width-15)*2, self.ViewB.frame.size.height)];
self.scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: still the issue occurs.

Comment: Strange.. its working for me. I tried it out now, its working for me.

Comment: could you please post your complete code. it would be very useful

Comment: The number of lines were more for a comment, so i have edited and added the code in the answer.

Comment: directionalLockEnabled doesn't disable the diagonal scroll, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619390-directionallockenabled?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked well for me. In my case, determining the direction at the beginning of the drag using the scrollView panGestureRecognizer allowed for pinning the direction for the rest of the scroll:

```
private var draggingVertically : Bool = true
private var initialContentOffset = CGPoint.zero
public func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    initialContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    
    let velocity = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.velocity(in: scrollView.superview)
    draggingVertically = abs(velocity.x) < abs(velocity.y)
}


public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var offset = scrollView.contentOffset
    if (draggingVertically == true){
        offset.x = initialContentOffset.x
    } else {
        offset.y = initialContentOffset.y
    }
    scrollView.contentOffset = offset
}
```